# How to disable Kivy's default hotkeys

Tags: python, kivy

So basically I'm making a program that requires a lot of keys binding, but the problem is that some of the available keys have been taken as hotkey in Kivy.

For example, when the app running and you press "Esc" the app will exit, or when you press "f1" the Kivy app will appear a setting panel (I'm not sure if there's more).

So is there any way to disable all of these features so I can use them as my personal keys?

I have tried looking in the kivy.config but I don't think I can understand them...

Comment: Not sure whether it's an effective solution, but did you try binding with keyboard and managing each keycode separately ?

Comment: @ApuCoder I did. But after it execute the traceback I bound, it continues to do the Kivy hotkey work.